# redhat find all packages installed locally

Tags: redhat, installation, repository

So far I have a list of explicit packages that are installed with yum. The server has some of its own developed software which would not be from a repo, it would be moved and then installed locally. Is there a way to find out which packages/software have been installed this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
rpm -qa
```

to list all installed packages. This will also list the ones from repos. Then you could compare against the repo installed ones, eliminate the duplicates, and find your locally installed ones.

```
rpm -qi {package}
```

Will display information about the installed package.

You can also look up the `rpm` man pages for more options.

Answer (score 1):

Packages installed with the rpm command and not through a yum repo get listed with "installed" as their origin. A simple:

```
 yum list installed |grep installed
```

should list those.

Software that wasn't packaged, but installed by copying binaries or compiled from source will not be listed in the rpm database and can only be found by examining the file system. Your only hope is that if your colleagues did that;  they at least followed some convention and installed custom software in /usr/local, /opt or another single path and not in /bin or /usr/sbin etc.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "installed locally"? Something like "rpm -ivh package.rpm"?

If yes, then you can find all packages from non-official repos by something like this:

rpm -qa --qf '%{NAME} %{VENDOR}\n' | grep -v "Red Hat"

Also

yum list installed |awk '{if ($3=="installed") print $1}'

will help you. it will show not only local-installed packages but also all packages that you didn't update since first install OS...so It's not very useful if you have many non-updated packages.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know there is no easy way to do this. Obviously you can use:

```
rpm -qa | grep package-name
```

To find a certain packae or drop the grep and list all installed packages via yum. But if you install from source (which is I assume what you are doing - you didn't specify) they wouldn't be tracked by yum. If they have been installed from source, the normal procedure would be to download the source files to /usr/src and run make and make install from there. So normally, you would have all the source files in the /usr/src folder. But, if anyone has installed software without placing the source files there, or they have deleted the source since installing it you wouldn't find them there.